# Obtain an array with notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to put notifications in an array as they become available, but the count of the array is reset to 1 when I push a new notification.

This is the code:

```
    int r = 0;
    listMsgReceived = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (notification)
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notification received" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", message]  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertView show];
        [listMsgReceived insertObject:message atIndex:r];
        r++;
        NSLog(@"apres: %d \n", [listMsgReceived count]);
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you're probably using a local variable for `r` that is being set to 0 before every notification, but it's hard to tell for sure with limited code.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are initializing the variables `r` and `listMsgReceived` each time your notification is received (though it's hard to tell from the context you provided).

You should not do that, because that gets you a *new* array each time, where you insert one object - hence the count will be one after each notification.

You could try moving your array initialization outside of your method; declare it as a property on your class and initialize it in the initializer.

Comment: yes, you are right. thanks a lot for your answer and to take the time for my question. have a good day!